# Using MetaData to Link Sharepoint Pages to multiple Subsites

Tags: document-library, sub-site, pages

A Sharepoint (Landingpage) site Links to multiple Subsites. These sub-sites are Industrial Verticals( Oil & Gas, Financial Services, Healthcare, etc) or Technology categories( Computer vision, Translation, Block-chain, Etc). Making up all these subsites are Pages. These pages all contain usecases and the files that are shared with these usecases.

I would like to tag each page with Meta-data like the industrial Vertical and the technology category used. Using that tagging I would like the subset pages to show up in corresponding pages. The attached pictures shows a graphical representation of what I mean.

I have tried using Quick Link but I have to strictly specify what pages Quick LInk shows. It will not pull from the recently created pages according to the meta data.

Any tips on where to look or steps to take would be appreciated.

[image: Share_Site layout]

Comment: You could probably use Content By Search webpart to make this dynamic, as outlined (very briefly) here: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2013/12/filter-search-results-by-managed.html . You will find more details by searching this site, and the web

Comment: thank you @RobertLindgren RIght now I am using a sort of filtering of Site content to match Metadata which seems to be useful but not the slickest solution. I Will investigate this method a little further.

Answer (score 0):

In the End what I did was create everything, both categories( in graphic as subsites) and pages, as Pages for in Sharepoint. Then in each Page I tagged with certain meta data like Technology used and a vertical. Then on each Vertical related page I have a librayr which listed on pages. The listed pages can have customized filter and there I filtered it for the pertinent category ( ex. Manufacturing vertical) so any page with that in the meta data would be shown in the list and those wihtout would not.

This seems to be a decent solution and has bee working well so far.